# Lucene.net PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper

Tags: lucene, analyzer

I've read on how to use the per field analyzer wrapper, but can't get it to work with a custom analyzer of mine. I can't even get the analyzer to run the constructor, which makes me believe I'm actually calling the per field analyzer incorrectly.

Here's what I'm doing:

Create the per field analyzer:

```
PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper perFieldAnalyzer = new  PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(srchInfo.GetAnalyzer(true));
perFieldAnalyzer.AddAnalyzer("<special field>", dta);
```

Add all the fields do document as usual, including a special field that we analyze differently.

And add document using the analyzer like this:

```
iw.AddDocument(doc, perFieldAnalyzer);
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Assuming you are using Lucene 3.x, that looks all right, to me.  Is an exception being thrown?  What, exactly, is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to my reliance on CMSs (Kentico) built-in Lucene helper classes. Basically, using those classes you need to specify the custom analyzer at index-level through the CMS and I did not wish to do that. So I ended up using Lucene.net directly almost everywhere gaining the flexibility of using any custom analyzer I want

I also did some changes to how I structure data and ended up using the tried-and-true KeywordAnalyzer to analyze document tags. Previously I was trying to do some custom tokenization magic on comma separated values like [tag1, tag2, tag with many parts] and could not get it reliably working with multi-parted tags. I still kept that field, but started adding multiple "tag" fields to the document, each storing one tag. So now I have N "tag" fields for "N" tags, each analyzed as a keyword, meaning each tag (one word or many) is a single token.

I think I overthinked it with my initial approach.

Here is what I ended up with.

On Indexing:

```
KeywordAnalyzer ka = new KeywordAnalyzer();
PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper perFieldAnalyzer = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(srchInfo.GetAnalyzer(true));
perFieldAnalyzer.AddAnalyzer("documenttags_t", ka);

-- Some procedure to compile all documents by reading from DB and putting into Lucene docs

foreach(var doc in docs)
{
   iw.AddDocument(doc, perFieldAnalyzer);
}
```

On Searching:

```
KeywordAnalyzer ka = new KeywordAnalyzer();
PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper perFieldAnalyzer = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(srchInfo.GetAnalyzer(true));
perFieldAnalyzer.AddAnalyzer("documenttags_t", ka);

string baseQuery = "documenttags_t:\"" + tagName + "\"";
Query query = _parser.Parse(baseQuery);
var results = _searcher.Search(query, sortBy)
```